# If I leave a Colosseum event indefinitely, will the element change or stay the same?

Tags: dragonvale

As I still have a ways to go in the game in terms of levels, I still get Colosseum events for dragon elements I don't yet have.  In some cases (Metal) I'd like to just do it and get it over with.  In others (Air) I might breed one relatively quickly and then start it.  If I leave the Colosseum event indefinitely will the element ever change?  If so, how long does that take?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the event in the Colosseum event changes every 24hrs. That is without a dragon. If there is a dragon in the Colosseum then the event will not change until u finish the event and claim your reward. Happy to help.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  This confirms what I have observed as well.